# Showing two compound propositions are logically equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How to show that, $\lnot(p \leftrightarrow q)$ and $p \leftrightarrow \lnot q$ are logically equivalent without using truth table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sim(p\leftrightarrow q)\\ \equiv \sim((p\rightarrow q)\wedge (q\rightarrow p))\\ \equiv \sim(p\rightarrow q)\vee\sim(q\rightarrow p)\\ \equiv \sim(\sim p\vee q)\vee\sim(\sim q\vee p)\\ \equiv(p\wedge \sim q)\vee(q\wedge \sim p)\\ \equiv (p\vee q)\wedge (\sim p\vee\sim q)\\ \equiv (\sim q\rightarrow p)\wedge (p\rightarrow\sim q)\\ \equiv p\leftrightarrow\sim q$

Comment: I don't understand the transformation from 5th line to 6th line. Is this a law?

Comment: That is by application of distribution and negation laws.

Answer (score 0):

A hint to a solution: Split into two cases:

- p and q have the same truth value
- p and q have different truth values

Can you see how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick non-formal proof:

We know that any biconditional $p \leftrightarrow q$ is true if and only if $p$ and $q$ have the same truth-value

So:

$\neg (p \leftrightarrow q)$ iff

not $p \leftrightarrow q$ iff

$p$ and $q$ have opposite truth-values iff

$\neg p$ and $q$ have the same truth-value iff

$\neg p \leftrightarrow q$